# Singular Values Decomposition (SVD) with R

Tags: r, math, matrix, svd

The SVD works well with R:

```
A = matrix(1:12,3,4)
A
u = svd(A)$u
v = svd(A)$v
sigma = diag(svd(A)$d)
u %*% sigma %*% t(v)   # = A as desired
```

But unlike [the usual statement of the SVD theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Statement_of_the_theorem), `v` is **not** a 4x4 matrix (it should be!):

```
dim(v)   # (4,3)
```

**Why is it so?**

According to the theorem,

- `v` should be of format (4,4),
- `sigma` should be of format (3,4).
  By the way what would be shortest way to create a `diag(svd(A)$d)` zero-padded in order to be of format (3,4)?

Comment: Look a the "Thin SVD" in the same wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Reduced_SVDs  by the way you can still use the `nv` parameter inside the `svd` function (`s = svd(A, nv = ncol(A)`) and for sigma you can do something like this `sigma = cbind(diag(s$d), 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the full **U** and **V** matrices, use the `nu=` and `nv=` arguments to `svd()`. To pad a diagonal matrix with zeros, use the `nrow=` and `ncol=` arguments to `diag()`:

```
A <- matrix(1:12,3,4)
D <- svd(A, nu=nrow(A), nv=ncol(A))
u <- D$u
v <- D$v
sigma <- diag(D$d, nrow=nrow(A), ncol=ncol(A))

## Check that that worked:
dim(u)
# [1] 3 3
dim(v)
# [1] 4 4
dim(sigma)
# [1] 3 4
u %*% sigma %*% t(v)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2    5    8   11
# [3,]    3    6    9   12
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just a different convention, different systems/textbooks will define the SVD one or the other way.  The important thing is the unitary property `U*U'=I`.  In either convention the singular vectors will minimize the least-squared distances in projection.

Here's a development of the theory that has the dimension conventions the same as in LINPACK and R:  https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring12/cos598C/svdchapter.pdf

Answer (score 1):

For part two:

```
diag(c(svd(A)$d,0),nrow=3,ncol=4)
```